# Validation rule - account executives can't edit closed won opportunity

Tags: validation-rule

I need to make a validation rule for Opportunities to make sure AEs can't edit closed won opportunity stages. The syntax for the rule I made works but when I log in as an AE I can change the opportunity stage without getting an error message.

```
AND(
    CONTAINS($UserRole.Name, 'Account.Executives') ,
    ISCHANGED(StageName) ,
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),'Closed Won')
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd expect the issue to be you looking for 'Account.Executives' in the _Id_ of your user role rather than the _name_ of your user role.

Comment: Ok I changed that to $UserRole.Name and tried both these versions of the rule:  1) CONTAINS( $UserRole.Name, 'Account.Executives') &&
 ISCHANGED(StageName) &&
 TEXT(PriorValue(StageName))= "Closed Won"

Comment: 2) CONTAINS( $UserRole.Name, 'Account.Executives') && ISCHANGED(StageName) &&  ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),'Closed Won')

Comment: please use [edit] to amend your post with latest VR; avoid comment

Answer (score 0):

In `contains` you have to put a string with the name of the userRole, like "Executive Staff".

```
AND(
    CONTAINS($UserRole.Name, 'Executive Staff') ,
    ISCHANGED(StageName) ,
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),'Closed Won')
)
```